# Ruby on Rails n00b. rake db:migrate fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake, dbmigrate

new to ROR. i'm taking one month rails and :

i cannot get past f'n $ rake db:migrate!!!!

I'm getting this message now

```
gregs-MacBook-Air:trydah gregfrontiero
$ rake db:migrate

== 20140606025644 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================

-- change_table(:users)

rake aborted!

StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
```

> `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/gregfrontiero/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`initialize' "`

I saw something on StackOverflow saying to reset and got this:

```
gregs-MacBook-Air:trydah gregfrontiero$ rake db:reset
```

> `/Users/gregfrontiero/Desktop/trydah/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run`rake db:migrate`to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /Users/gregfrontiero/Desktop/trydah/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.`

If you let me know how to fix this, i will build several shrines in your honor.

Thanks again,

Greg

Comment: `users` does not exist as a table. You need to create it before altering it.

Comment: thanks jken. i'm super new to programming. how would i create a 'users' table?

Comment: The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are incredibly helpful when you're just getting started with Rails. To learn how to create and alter tables, check out the [Database Migrations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the error clearly states this:

```
no such table: users
```

The problem you have is you're trying to change a table which does not exist. If you have created the table in previous migrations & deleted on your server, you may want to use `rake db:reset`, however as you've already used that command with errors, you'll probably have to set up a new table.

--

I think you'll be best doing this:

```
$ rails g migration CreateUserTable

#db/[timestamp]_create_users.rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
        #... columns here
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If you then remove the content out of the migration you have currently - allowing you to run this new one, you'll be able to create the database by running `rake db:migrate`. After that, you need to create a new migration, copy the commented-out one, and paste into the new one.

This will allow you to run the `change` commands in your database, as the db will be present on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try starting with:

```
rake db:setup
```

then

```
rake db:migrate
```

Also, if you have setup Devise before you've created your database, you may need to comment out the `devise_for :users` line in your routes.rb.

When your rails environment is loaded during `rake` it loads routes, which calls this `devise_for :users` which is looking for your users table, which doesn't yet exist and is the very thing that you're trying to create.